# Steam Games Not Launching (I’ve Tried Everything!)

Tags: steam, windows-10

I have had my Dell XPS 8900 for several years, during which I was able to play all of my Steam games just fine. Recently, I have found that nearly all of my Steam games crash/fail to launch, and the “running” status on Steam simply reverts back to “Play.” I’ve tried verifying files integrity, reinstalling each game, reinstalling Steam, and I even reset my pc to factory default. After downloading Steam on the fresh start, it still would not launch the Steam games. Any suggestions?

Comment: We are going to need some extra information to help with this: Which Windows 10 Build? (press the Windows key + R, write winver and press enter) What version of Steam? (go to Help and then to About Steam) Which Graphics Card does your system has?

Comment: Do you have any third-party software (like aggressive anti-virus programs) running in the background that might interfere? Are all your drivers up-to-date?

Comment: @Lemon It’s OS build 19041.1052. Graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce GT 730. Steam version 1623193086. I have McAfee antivirus

Comment: I have had this same setup for a while I’m pretty sure. Haven’t had any problems until recently. Although, it does seem that the issue happens when the resolution is adjusted by the games. I could be wrong though. Cuphead works perfectly, even when it changes to full screen, while almost all my other games fail.

Comment: In fact, when I was unable to play Castle Crashers, etc. I was able to play Terraria. Then, after a little bit, Terraria stopped working suddenly, too. Cuphead has had no issues

Comment: Open your task manager and see if the game's executable tries to launch and then gets terminated. You can open up Event Viewer and check for fatal errors around the time you tried launching a game. It should provide information as to why something keeps crashing.

Comment: After running Fallout New Vegas, obviously resulting in a failure, I checked the event viewer. It shows that the faulting module name is nvd3dum.dll. Then, I tried running Castle Crashers, and discovered that it also had nvd3dum.dll as the faulting module. Im guessing nvd3dum.dll has something to do with my NVIDIA graphics card. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much a library for your graphics card (the "nvd" is iconic for NVidia and the "3d" is self-explanatonary for something 3D-rendering realated). Try to check your graphic card's driver, reinstall it if necessary. Also check your DirectX (i don't know up to which version your graphics card supports). DirectX does a lot of driver managing for your graphics card. Check if after reset you run the latest possible DirectX version.

Comment: Can you [perform a driver rollback](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/driver-rollback/) and see if that works?

Answer (score 2):

Really, and I'm gonna push the envelope here and post it as an answer, it sounds a bug not with steam, but the game crashing on boot.

Steam tries to launch the game (shows running), the game crashes with no message, but steam detects the game is no longer running so it goes back to the 'Play' button.

So now, why? I don't know with the information given here and it could be loads of things.

Can you run any game that is not booted via steam (Like with the epic store launcher)? Are all games you have/tried linked in some way (like if they are all unity based or something)

If you can't, I'm gonna guess a firewall or antivirus or even a virus is overbearing and basically stops anything using processes that could apply to games as soon as they appear. And since the crash is not a crash that is expected by the games, no message is shown.